# How to graph $x-y \leq z$ where the function is only defined in a triangle.

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm really bad at graphing more "difficult" equations. I get lost in the constraints. Could anyone give me tips and show me what the graph of the following equation should look like?

We have two random variables $X$ and $Y \in [0,1]$. $X$ and $Y$ only take on values within a triangle with vertices $(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0)$. What would the graph of $x-y \leq z$ with $x \geq y$ look like within this triangle?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For each z in (-1,1), this is the interior of the trapezoid with vertices (0,0), (.5,.5), (.5(1+z),.5(1-z)) and (0,-z).

Comment: @Did PERFECT! That's what I got using the help you and Andre gave me from the other question you commented on. Thank you!